# Discard command-line contents when receiving remote keys

Tags: command-line, autocmd, clientserver

If Vim command-line is being edited and the Vim instance receives a string due to `vim --remote-send KEYS` executed on a shell somewhere, result is somewhat equivalent to pressing `Return` in the command-line and typing the received `KEYS` afterwards. Since the command that is unintentially executed can be hard to recover (an artificial example could be `!rm -rf *`), is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Initial idea was to send e.g. `<Esc><Esc>KEYS` to discard any possible active input in the receiving Vim instance. This does quit a potentially active Insert mode and prevents `KEYS` landing in the current buffer. But this is does not work for the command-line input.

I was thinking of some autocommand-event to trigger user confirmation upon remote keys receipt, but none of available events looked right for the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution (not perfect) is to use `Ctrl-C` instead, for example:

```
vim --remote-send '<c-c>:echo "test"<cr>'
```

This seems to work in command-line, normal, insert and visual mode, but not in operator-pending mode (at least in my test, after pressing `va` from normal mode with no timeouts).

Comment: This solves indeed the problem of unintended command executions. Concerning your example with `va`, sending just `<c-c>` first, followed by `<c-c>KEYS` puts Vim back to Normal mode and interpret `KEYS` as expected.